# Dynamically binding resources with data-win-res attribute

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have an object which contains the id of the resource to be loaded and want to bind it inside the template itself.
Normally resources can be bound like this:

```
<div class="description" data-win-res="{textContent:'taxCalDescription'}" ></div>
<div class="name" data-win-bind="textContent:'TaxCal'" ></div>
```

where `resid` is the id of the string resource. But instead of having the id directly, I have an object, one of whose elements is the resource id. Say I have an object,

```
var tool = {
    name: "TaxCal",
    descriptionResId : "taxCalDescription"
}
```

I tried binding it like this,

```
<div class="description" data-win-res="{textContent: tool.descriptionResId}" ></div>
<div class="name" data-win-bind="textContent:tool.name" ></div>
```

While the `data-win-bind` can access the `tool` object, `data-win-res` can't. It throws an error stating that `'cannot find descriptionResId of undefined'`

So, how can I bind a dynamic resource id to a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in this situation you need to change your use the resource API's directly.

You can do this in one of two ways:

1. *Make your data offer up the localized string*: When you come to load you're localized name, you can call `WinJS.Resources.getString` with the resource ID
2. Use `WinJS.Binding.converter` to dynamically load it based on the incoming value. E.g.

Example:

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("YourNamespace", {
    loadToolName: WinJS.Binding.converter(function(input) {
        switch(input) {
            case "notlocalizedname":
                return WinJS.Resources.getString("MyID");
            default:
                return "Unknown";
        }
    }),
});
```

Then, in your markup, your bind would look like:

```
<div class="description"
     data-win-bind="textContent: tool.descriptionResId YourNamespace.loadToolName">
</div>
```